# How to select an anchor inside several other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in my CSS:

```
#slider div.mc-caption a
```

How can I select this element via JQuery?
Thanks.

Comment: That's called a _selector_.

Comment: ... And jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ... this is known as selector

```
console.log($('#slider div.mc-caption a'));
$('#slider div.mc-caption a').click(function()
        {alert('Testing')});
```

and with HTML

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="mc-caption"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Testing</a></div>
</div>
```

[Click here for fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mz_arain08/Lpa6r/)